# How to generate a cross join table, having one of the IDs from a range in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatables, cross-join

I have a table with the total number of secondary IDs per each principal ID. So I need to generate a second table in which each row correspond to the combination of primary ID and Secondary ID. For example if for primary ID1 I have 5 as the number of secondary ids I would need 5 rows, each with the same Primary ID and the second ID going from 1 to 5. Doing this with a loop takes a lot of time so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this without involving loops.

Visual example:

**Table**

[image]

**Table Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with `.groupby`:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame( np.repeat(df['ID'], df['Number_of_IDs']) )
df_out['ID2'] = df_out.groupby(df_out['ID'])['ID'].transform(lambda x: range(len(x))) + 1

print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
    ID  ID2
0  ID1    1
0  ID1    2
0  ID1    3
1  ID2    1
1  ID2    2
2  ID3    1
3  ID4    1
3  ID4    2
```

---

Or:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame( np.repeat(df['ID'], df['Number_of_IDs']) )
df_out['ID2'] = 1
df_out['ID2'] = df_out.groupby(df_out['ID'])['ID2'].cumsum()

print(df_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function on the number of IDs and then use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on the dataframe.

```
df['Number_of_IDs'] = df['Number_of_IDs'].apply(lambda x : range(1, x+1))
df = df.explode('Number_of_IDs'))
df = df.rename(columns={'Number_of_IDs': 'ID2'})
```

Output-

```
   ID   ID2
0  ID1    1
0  ID1    2
0  ID1    3
1  ID2    1
1  ID2    2
2  ID3    1
3  ID4    1
3  ID4    2
```